# Google Music Play reports "Can't download music right now. Will try again later."

Tags: google-play-music

I have a rooted Galaxy Tab 2 running Android 4.2.2 and Google Music version 5.6.1609P.1258283. I try to download albums and all goes well for approximately 5 albums. After that, Google Play Music reports:

> Can't download music right now. Will try again later.

Later never comes, and any attempt to restart the download fails with the same error message. I have plenty of disk space.

I have a decent amount of Unix/Linux experience, so I started an attempt to diagnose. I checked logcat as root and it gave me this:

```
# logcat D
...
E/DownloadTaskImpl(12712): IOException: id=[3202, DEFAULT], remoteId=7b000cd1-13b5-3f89-8117-65e65dff70d0, owner=KEEPON, priority=100, seek=0
E/DownloadTaskImpl(12712): Download failed because of IO Error: The target server failed to respond
...
```

I get the IOException every time I try to restart the download. I logged this issue with Google support, but never got a response.

Any suggestions are welcome.